# MongoDb Full text search eats memory when i search on com and other small words

Tags: php, mongodb

Thank you for reading this, i have an collection with full text th index size is of the index is 809.7MB (Mongo Compass) but when i search for com or other small words the memory is full (8GB memory).

Its a sharding.

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

what are your indexes?  small words sounds like they are not the first, left most characters of the field...you have a wild card in front of the word?...if so it is a very inefficient search...

Comment: I have 1 text index with 2 fields:
1.from (text)(100) (Contains an email adres)
2 subject (text)(80) (Contains an subject from emails)

Search query
{ $text: { $search: 'com' }}

No you can only search on words that are larger than 3 and i only allow AZaz09. Multiple words are put together with a space between. 

I do allow operaters ", +, -

Comment: right - I get that you have a compound index - - but your search is not using it...  for a text search to use the index you must search on the beginning, left-most characters...if not all docs must be touched. (there is something called partial index that could be useful) .. but one must work backwards from the queries that one will be doing to then create the index they need.  a total wild text query will not be an index user..

Comment: I thought this is only when i do a regex search then its less expencive to begin at the first charactor, but i can only use the full text search on an index. I wil try to do an explain query to see how much objects are scanned. And come back here.

See documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/

Answer (score 0):

if I understand; your text search then must touch every document.

perhaps you have no alternative but the way to do a faster query is to: 
a. match to the index 
b. text search on the beginning letters i.e. ^ symbol as search the first letters is much more efficient than searching anywhere in the string...

if this is not possible, and text searching is going to be a major component of your application you would consider some strategies:
* create key search words as part of the data input that can be used by the text query process
* delimit the pool of possible docs in some way perhaps a date range, topic, etc - - ultimately you probably would want to index on these and include them in your text query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, why would it need to go trough all the documents? Its text search right it has an index and i thought it would use the index, also if you see the memory its increasing so fast its like a memory leak.

I already have date ranges etc arround the query bit still i think its weird that mongo eats memory espacalie because the query has an index.

Comment: just trying to help... but if the search is for /com/ and that can be any 3 character set, in any position, in the email field.....   then it needs to look at all documents.  if I understand you correctly that isn't a mongo issue that is universal.  to search the telephone book for 'com' if it is the first 3 positions only ^com then can use the index but not if in any position...